# using Raphael with require js and eve js

Tags: raphael, require, eve

I am familiar with Raphael.js and I am using it in my web application.

But,What is the purpose of converting the Raphael java script file into modules published in the this article https://github.com/vraa/raphael-require

The new module files are---> raphael.svg.js,  raphael.core.js, raphael.vml.js, raphel.amd.js and raphael.eve.js

But they have not told how to use these new files

It has been told told that , by doing this we can use raphael with eve.js.

Since this concept is entirely new to me, I wanted to know the purpose of doing this.If any one has already done some thing with this , then it will be highly helpful for me .Since I can adopt this approach in my application to get better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved . 
Require.js taken from DOJO javascript library. 
After experimenting with samples given in DOJO site I am able to use require.js properly.